# Variables behaving badly - in JavaScript - in functions

Tags: javascript, variables

First off, here's my code:

```
var variable1 = 10;
function f1 (){
  alert(variable1);
}
//When button is pressed, call function
$("#button").click(f1);
```

Why can I not access variable1 inside the function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var how_many_words = 3;
  alert(how_many_words); //This happens

  $("input").keypress(check_word);

  function check_word() {
    alert('hello'); //This happens
    alert(how_many_words); //This doesn't
  }
});
```

Comment: Works for me. I assume this is your actual code and not something you stripped out to try and illustrate the problem?

Comment: +1 for comment, I also tried it in firebug and it worked fine for me!

Comment: Worked for me, too, in Firefox, IE, and Chrome. Check the HTML and ensure that the button is declared properly. Also, tell us what happens when you run it.

Comment: Your modified code works for me too. To verify that I got the second popup for how_many_words, I added the line

how_many_words = 42;

The second popup showed 42.

Comment: It doesn't seem right that the second alert simply doesn't happen. What browser are you using?


If the JavaScript interpreter thinks that how_many_words isn't defined in that scope, you should get an alert box with the text 'undefined'. (Try it -- change the 2nd alert in the callback to say alert(undefined) -- that way you'll be able to rule out variable scoping as the issue.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll have to sift through my code in the morning and I'll post back if I ever get an answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definitive answer to what my problem was, courtesy of [this website](http://www.javascriptjunkie.com/?p=12). I foolishly named one of my variables the same as an id and a function. Insanity! I apologise for wasting people's boxing days. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually not that you can't access the variable, but that the `#button` element is not in the DOM yet when your binding code is called. Wrap your initialization code in the jQuery DOM ready idiom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(f1);
});
```

Comment: This is only a snippet of much more code so that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var variable1 = 10;
 var f1 = function(){
     alert(variable1);
 }
 //When button is pressed, call function
 $("#button").click(f1);
```

Just mocked up your issue. Your code works fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="button">hello</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var variable1 = 10;
                function f1 (){
                    alert(variable1);
                }
                //When button is pressed, call function
                $("#button").click(f1);

            //]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: function x() { ... } is syntactic sugar for var x = function () { ... };.

Comment: I must have simplified my problem incorrectly. I'll come back with the correct question as soon as possible.

Comment: @AKX, actually, they're both VERY different - http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/

Comment: @J-P: Thanks for the clarification! I must've mixed Lua and JS up. In Lua, I'm fairly sure function x() end is sugary...

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that you **can** access `variable1` from inside of `f1`. What happens when you try?

<del>One thing I notice is that you're calling alert with an int argument. I'm not sure if that works. Try</del>

<del>alert(variable1.toString());</del>

<del>instead.</del>

**EDIT**: OK, never mind that bit; alert(int) certainly does work.